# How do I convert textile to Eclipse help using ant?

Tags: ant, eclipse-rcp, mylyn, textile, mylyn-wikitext

I've been using the [Mylyn WikiText User Guide](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui/help/Markup-Conversion.html) to learn how to convert textile files to Eclipse help but I also want to be able to do this using ant because, ultimately, I want to have [many textile files contribute to a single textile file then convert to Eclipse help](http://peterfriese.wordpress.com/page/2/) to enable multiple developers to create help pages with minimal conflicts.

The following ant script should take all *.textile files in the 'doc' folder and convert them to Eclipse help:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="helpwikitext" default="generate-help">
  <property name="wikitext.standalone" value="doc" />
  <path id="wikitext.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${wikitext.standalone}">
      <include name="org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.*core*.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <taskdef classpathref="wikitext.classpath" resource="org/eclipse/mylyn/wikitext/core/util/anttask/tasks.properties" />
  <target name="generate-help" description="Generate Eclipse help from textile source">
    <wikitext-to-eclipse-help markupLanguage="Textile" multipleOutputFiles="true" navigationImages="true" helpPrefix="help">
      <fileset dir="${basedir}">
        <include name="doc/*.textile" />
      </fileset>
      <stylesheet url="styles/help.css" />
      <stylesheet url="styles/main.css" />
     </wikitext-to-eclipse-help>
  </target>
</project>
```

I get the following error:

```
[taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/eclipse/mylyn/wikitext/core/util/anttask/tasks.properties. It could not be found.
build.xml:11: Problem: failed to create task or type wikitext-to-eclipse-help
```

I'm fairly sure that I have all the Mylyn features installed so it looks like the ant script doesn't know where to find them. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the wikitext standalone package installed in your `doc` directory?

That is what is expected as you define the path used by the taskdef like this:

```
<property name="wikitext.standalone" value="doc" />
```

I'll take a guess that your wikitext package is in a different dir.

You then use the same dir as the root for your textfiles. I would suggest to keep the wikitext standalone package separate from your textfiles.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I downloaded the standalone package from http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/downloads/, renamed the 'doc' folder to 'jars' and put the jars there.